# Mongoose.connect with async not working properly Please

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-modules

My code is not working in async manner

```
module.exports = async function(URL,socket){

    let mongoose = require("mongoose");
    let db ;
        try{
            await mongoose.connect(URL,{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true},function(){
                console.log("Connected With the User DataBase");
                socket.emit("connected_user","Connected With your Database");
                    db  = mongoose.connection;
            });
            console.log("After the connected");
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
   
    return DB;
    
}
```

This is how I want the output; it should print

> Connected With the User Datbase

then emit the event, and then print

> After the connected

but it's working in the opposite way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the callback and await both.

As I can see the connect method does not need a callback function, hence you can do like

```
module.exports = async function(URL,socket){

    let mongoose = require("mongoose");
    let db ;
        try{
            await mongoose.connect(URL,{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true});
            console.log("Connected With the User DataBase");
            socket.emit("connected_user","Connected With your Database");
            db  = mongoose.connection;
            console.log("After the connected");
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }

    return DB;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use async/await in you code,

```
module.exports = async function(URL, socket) {
  let mongoose = require("mongoose");
  let db;
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(URL, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }, async function() {
      console.log("Connected With the User DataBase");
      await socket.emit("connected_user", "Connected With your Database");
      db = mongoose.connection;
    });
    console.log("After the connected");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  return DB;
}
```